# Change tmux window title dynamically to last line of command output

Tags: zsh, tmux, output, window-title

I would like that every stdout in a specific tmux window is *dynamically* redirected to

```
any command | tmux window-rename
```

That is, the last line of output always becomes the title of the window.

I run an interactive shell (zsh) session in that window.

I encountered two problems:

- Output is redirected after the command finished, not during the completion
- Somehow tmux window-rename will complain about wrong usage

Comment: Are you running a specific program in the tmux window? Or is it an interactive shell session?

Comment: Hi Gilles, its a zsh session. Let us assume I invoke 'date' in the shell, I will be given the date, and this output I would like to have as title of my tmux window.

Comment: Ok. That's not something the shell can do: it doesn't see command output. You need to modify tmux, or to put something (e.g. an expect script) between tmux and the shell+applications. Do you could the shell prompt line as command output, or is it an exception?